# Go TCP timeout not working?

Tags: tcp, timeout, go

I'm using `net.Listen()` to listen TCP connections from clients.

When client established a connection, `Handler(conn net.Conn)` will handle it.

```
func Handler(conn net.Conn) {

  read_len, err := conn.Read(request)

  if err != nil {
    if neterr, ok := err.(net.Error); ok && neterr.Timeout() {
      fmt.Println(neterr)
      PILOG("Client timeout!", PILOGWARNING)
      conn.Close()
      return
  }
}
```

I used a test client to connect then kill the client suddenly without sending a `DISCONNECT` message. My server should close the connection when reached timeout, but after a long waiting time it never happen.

I've also tried `conn.SetReadDeadline(time.Now())` but seems it still not working. So I wonder what the default TCP timeout in go, and how can I set it?

I also used `netstat -n` and got the result below after killed the client:

`tcp4       0      0  127.0.0.1.12345    127.0.0.1.57296    CLOSE_WAIT`

What does `CLOSE_WAIT` mean?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`SetReadDeadline`](http://golang.org/pkg/net/#TCPConn.SetReadDeadline) works AFAIK, but `SetReadDeadline(time.Now())` has no reasonable use and that's the problem, I believe. To make a timeout of, for example N seconds *from now* use:

```
SetReadDeadline(time.Now().Add(N*time.Second))
```

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol)

> **CLOSE-WAIT**
>
> (both server and client) represents waiting for a connection termination request from the local user.

Comment: @ReckHou: It's hard to help having no complete, compilable and minimal code to either reproduce the stdlib bug or to look at and try to find a bug of yours. I seem to recall using the deadlines and they worked for me IIRC.